# JQ contains output

Tags: jq

I am trying to retrieve the values containg contoso.  So my output in this case should just readdata_contoso and writedata_contoso but I am having issues.  I am trying `jq -e -r ".roles[] | select(.name | contains("cont"))"`

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "name": "readdata_contoso",
      "permissions": {
        "": [
          "ReadData"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "writedata_contoso",
      "permissions": {
        "": [
          "WriteData"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What error/problem do you encounter? Seems like your code [should work fine](https://jqplay.org/s/WFSJKPuZWI)

Comment: i just end up with a smaller piece of the json.  I am trying to pull only the name out.  I end up with {
  "name": "readdata_contoso",
  "permissions": {
    "": [
      "ReadData"
    ]
  }
}
{
  "name": "writedata_contoso",
  "permissions": {
    "": [
      "WriteData"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Check the link in my first comment, you need to add a `.name` afterward to select the "name" value rather than the object that contains it. And to simplify your code you could change it into `.roles[] | .name | select(contains("contoso"))` ([test it here](https://jqplay.org/s/gUyA3xwuo3)), selecting all the "name" values before applying a filter on them rather than on the objects that contain them

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help !

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. First, extract only the `name` of each role, then select those names which contain "contoso":

```
.roles[].name | select(contains("contoso"))
```

- `roles[].name` generates a list of all names
- `select(contains("contoso"))` only selects those names which contain "contoso"